# How to deal with null values in JQuery DataTable when using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm getting the following error when my page tries to load a DataTable:

> DataTables warning: table id=table1 - Requested unknown parameter '0'
>   for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/4

The table loading works fine when I use a dummy data set of random values, but the data I would like to display has many null values, and this may be why the problem arises. I would like to know how best to set the DataTable settings such that null values are recognized and displayed as an empty string.

I tried adding a render function to solve the issue (adapted from an example described in the comments on datatables oficial [forum](http://datatables.net/tn/4)), but it's not currently working, and I'm not sure how best to implement it, or if it would be better to use another method altogether.

jQuery:

```
function setupData() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#table1').dataTable({
            "dom": 'B<clear>frtip',
            "buttons": [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ],
            "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]],
            "scrollX": true,
            "scrollY": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/index_get_data",
                "dataType": "json",
                "dataSrc": "data",
                "contentType": "application/json"
            },
            responsive: true
        });
    });
}
$(window).on("load", setupData);
```

html:

```
<table contenteditable='true' id="table1" class="tableBody dataTable table-striped table-bordered nowrap display" style="width:100%" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {%  for item in cols %}
                <th>{{ item }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

A render function that I added to the dataTable declaration, but I couldn't get this to work:

```
"render": function jsRenderCOL(data, type, row, meta) {
    var dataRender;
    if (data == null) {
        dataRender = "";
    }
    return dataRender;
}
```

There are over 130 columns (this can be variable), and the data is updated daily, with many columns potentially containing null data. I'd like to find a method to display the data within the dataTable where the columns don't have to be declared explicitly within the dataTable function. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set the defaultContent on initialisation for each and every column to be an empty string i.e.

```
$('#table1').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
      "targets": (pass a variable in here that you have calculated based on the number of columns to render) 
      "defaultContent": ""
    } ]
} );
```

and for the targets attribute pass in a variable that defines the indexes of the columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that, and I'm no longer getting the error message, but every single entry in each column defined within the targets array is set to null. I have columns where only some values are null. Is there anything else in my implementation that you think might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: That targets attribute is stating that for those columns if you encounter a null value then default it to an empty string. Not sure how you are actually rendering the data as setupData is not included above.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not sure why it's not working in my case. I'm using Flask, and converting a pandas dataframe to json using: df_test = df_test.to_json(orient="table"). I'm then routing the json data to a url, accessed from the datatable using the ajax functionality.

Comment: With regards the targets attribute just pass in _all and that is read as a default for all columns (see https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs)

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to worry about ajax data use this code

```js
      $('.dataTable').dataTable({
                    destroy: true,
                    paging: true,
                    searching: true,
                    sort: true,
                    "ajax": {
                        url: '{{ url('users/datatable')}}',
                        type: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                        },

                        'data':{}
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        {data: 'id'},
                        {data: 'name'},
                        {data: 'email'},
                        {data: 'membership_no'},
                        {data: 'is_active'},
                        {data: 'varsity_session'},
                        {data: 'due_amount'},
                        {data: 'paid_amount'},
                        {data: 'created_at'},
                        {data: 'last_transaction_date'},
                        {data: 'action'},
                    ],
                    "columnDefs": [
                        {"bSortable": false, "targets": [1, 6]},
                        {"searchable": false, "targets": [4, 6]}
                    ],

                    lengthMenu: [[10, 50, 100, -1], [10, 50, 100, "All"]],
                    pageLength: 10,
                    "dom": 'Blfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            extend: 'copy',
                            text: 'copy',
                            className: 'btn btn-primary',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: 'th:not(:last-child)'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'csv',
                            text: 'csv',
                            className: 'btn btn-warning',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: 'th:not(:last-child)'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'excel',
                            text: 'excel',
                            className: 'btn btn-danger',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: 'th:not(:last-child)'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'pdf',
                            text: 'pdf',
                            className: 'btn btn-success',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: 'th:not(:last-child)'
                            }
                        },
                        {

                            extend: 'print',
                            text: 'print',
                            className: 'btn btn-btn-info',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: 'th:not(:last-child)'
                            }
                        }
                    ]


                });
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Where about in your code are the null data being addressed? And also, do you have a solution that doesn't require each column name to be declared? I have over a hundred columns, and different tables with different column spec. I am currently creating the tags for each column dynamically within the html using Jinja, so I think it shouldn't be necessary to declare them within the jquery also.

Comment: You can dynamically generate those colum and dynamic id to your data table. Datatable requires only a table nothing to do with your other HTML

Answer (score -1):

Add

columnDefs:[
{"render":function(data){if(data == "null") {return "-"} else {return data}}, "targets":"_all" },
],

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).